# When I connect a wireless device, the computer's WI-FI disconnects from the network

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, connection, headset

I bought a wireless headset, when I connect the USB Wireless transmitter, the computer's WI-FI starts to fail and it no longer connects to the network.

**PC:** Dell Inspiron 15 5510
**OS:** Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
**Headest:** Corsair Virtuoso

EDIT
**lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3** command result:

0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:a0f0] (rev 30)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:4070]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect the dongle. Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.